# How to pass data between windows and update window in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to make a custom colour selector with PyQt5, but I keep failing because I have little knowledge in this area.

The program displays the selected colour as a label. The colours are stored in a SQLITE3 database as hexcode and RGB. When I run the Design Window it will read the database and bring the necessary colour label to the front: The code and GUI picture are below:

[image]

```
class Ui_DesignWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, DesignWindow):...

    title_colours = [self.black, self.white, self.orange, self.pink, self.purple, self.red, self.yellow, self.green, self.blue]
    side_colours = [self.black_2, self.white_2, self.orange_2, self.pink_2, self.purple_2, self.red_2, self.yellow_2, self.green_2, self.blue_2]
    bday_colours = [self.black_3, self.white_3, self.orange_3, self.pink_3, self.purple_3, self.red_3, self.yellow_3, self.green_3, self.blue_3]
    wanni_colours = [self.black_4, self.white_4, self.orange_4, self.pink_4, self.purple_4, self.red_4, self.yellow_4, self.green_4, self.blue_4]
    danni_colours = [self.black_5, self.white_5, self.orange_5, self.pink_5, self.purple_5, self.red_5, self.yellow_5, self.green_5, self.blue_5]
    content_colours = [self.black_6, self.white_6, self.orange_6, self.pink_6, self.purple_6, self.red_6, self.yellow_6, self.green_6, self.blue_6]
    public_colours = [self.black_7, self.white_7, self.orange_7, self.pink_7, self.purple_7, self.red_7, self.yellow_7, self.green_7, self.blue_7]
    sat_colours = [self.black_8, self.white_8, self.orange_8, self.pink_8, self.purple_8, self.red_8, self.yellow_8, self.green_8, self.blue_8]
    sun_colours = [self.black_9, self.white_9, self.orange_9, self.pink_9, self.purple_9, self.red_9, self.yellow_9, self.green_9, self.blue_9]

    school_colours = [self.l_black, self.l_blue, self.l_green, self.l_orange, self.l_pink, self.l_purple, self.l_yellow, self.l_red]
    uni_colours = [self.l_black_2, self.l_blue_2, self.l_green_2, self.l_orange_2, self.l_pink_2, self.l_purple_2, self.l_yellow_2, self.l_red_2]

    design_data = extract_design_data()

    self.hex_colour(title_colours, design_data[0][0])
    self.hex_colour(side_colours, design_data[0][1])
    self.hex_colour(content_colours, design_data[0][5]) 
    self.hex_colour(sat_colours, design_data[0][7])
    self.hex_colour(sun_colours, design_data[0][8])

    self.rgb_colour(bday_colours, design_data[0][2])
    self.rgb_colour(wanni_colours, design_data[0][3])
    self.rgb_colour(danni_colours, design_data[0][4])
    self.rgb_colour(public_colours, design_data[0][6])

    self.hex_colour_light(school_colours, design_data[0][9])
    self.hex_colour_light(uni_colours, design_data[0][10])...

def hex_colour(self, colour_labels, colour_req):
    if colour_req == "000000":
        colour_labels[0].raise_()
    if colour_req == "FFFFFF":
        colour_labels[1].raise_()
    if colour_req == "FF9900":
        colour_labels[2].raise_()
    if colour_req == "FC03FC":
        colour_labels[3].raise_()
    if colour_req == "9700CF":
        colour_labels[4].raise_()
    if colour_req == "FF0000":
        colour_labels[5].raise_()
    if colour_req == "FFFF00":
        colour_labels[6].raise_()
    if colour_req == "00FF6E":
        colour_labels[7].raise_() 
    if colour_req == "006EFF":
        colour_labels[8].raise_()

def rgb_colour(self, colour_labels, colour_req):
    if colour_req == "0 0 0":
        colour_labels[0].raise_()
    if colour_req == "255 255 255":
        colour_labels[1].raise_()
    if colour_req == "255 153 0":
        colour_labels[2].raise_()
    if colour_req == "252 3 252":
        colour_labels[3].raise_()
    if colour_req == "151 0 207":
        colour_labels[4].raise_()
    if colour_req == "255 0 0":
        colour_labels[5].raise_()
    if colour_req == "255 255 0":
        colour_labels[6].raise_()
    if colour_req == "0 255 110":
        colour_labels[7].raise_() 
    if colour_req == "0 110 255":
        colour_labels[8].raise_()

def hex_colour_light(self, colour_labels, colour_req):
    if colour_req == "8F8F8F":
        colour_labels[0].raise_()
    if colour_req == "8DFDFF":
        colour_labels[1].raise_()
    if colour_req == "B8FFD7":
        colour_labels[2].raise_()
    if colour_req == "FFCF87":
        colour_labels[3].raise_()
    if colour_req == "FFB5FF":
        colour_labels[4].raise_()
    if colour_req == "B399FF":
        colour_labels[5].raise_()
    if colour_req == "FDFC79":
        colour_labels[6].raise_()
    if colour_req == "FF9C9C":
        colour_labels[7].raise_()
```

I am just a beginner in coding and Python, so please let me know if what I have done is not the correct way.

After this, you can click the buttons and a pop-up window will appear. In this window you can select the colour and click done, clicking done will close the pop-up window.

I can update the data base based on what colour they have clicked, but my problem is how can I update the Design Window?

Could you please help me do this?
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it is a bit difficult to help you, as your code is missing *a lot* of things, and without them it's even hard to understand how your code *works*. For instance, what is `extract_design_data` and what does it return? That said, three important suggestions: 1. pyuic generated files should ***never*** be edited; use pyuic again with the original ui files to create *new* files and **never change them manually**, then create a ***new*** script that will be your actual program, and follow the suggestions of [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)

Comment: 2. you're using 9 labels for 9 groups; that's 81 individual objects that you probably individually and painfully created and aligned in designer; a simpler solution would be to create a single label for each group and just set a simple stylesheet for it: `background: black` and so on; this will make things easier when trying to get or set those colors; 3. it seems clear that you're not using [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), which is highly discouraged; if you do the above (2), you can easily use layouts [even in designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Comment: Thank you for that information! I am new to all this, so thank you for helping me fix my stupid errors haha. I'll update my code using the stylesheet! Also I am sorry for not providing enough information.

The extract_design_data function just goes to the data base and extracts the data from the table that contains the selected colours for each part of the excel sheet (title, side headings, bdays, etc).

Also, just out of curiosity, why is it not recommended to edit the files pyuic creates?

Comment: There are many reasons, one of the most important is that if at any point you need to make changes to the UI in Designer, merging the existing code with the new one is difficult, painful, annoying and almost always leads to errors because you missed some parts or made the wrong copy/paste. Other reasons are important as well, including the fact that using those classes usually leads to confusion about object structure and implementation. In the last releases of PyQt, the warning on top of those files make it more clear: you should not edit them, unless you *really* know what you're doing.